# Translate LINQ to LAMBDA Entity Framework Core using INCLUDE (NOT JOIN)

Tags: asp.net, linq, lambda, expression, entity

How to call multiple entities using Include method (not Join method) in Entity Framework Core? I am trying to translate this LINQ query to EF Core 5 syntax, but I do not know how to call multiple entities and join them together using include method.

```
        var reservations = from reservation in _dbContext.Reservations
                           join customer in _dbContext.Users on reservation.UserId equals customer.Id
                           join movie in _dbContext.Movies on reservation.MovieId equals movie.Id

                           select new
                           {
                               Id = reservation.Id,
                               ReservationTime = reservation.ReservationTime,
                               CustomerName = customer.Id,
                               MovieName = movie.Name
                           };
```

I tried using multiple include and select method, but do not know how to call multiple entities and join

Here are my models

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReservationTime { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlayingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlayingTime { get; set; }
    public double TicketPrice { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string TrailorUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
        var reservations = _dbContext.Reservations
            .Include(r => r.Id)
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ReservationTime, x.User, x.User.Name });
```

Comment: `Include` and `Select` are mutual exclusive operators. What you can do here it is only simplify query by using navigation properties. So better add model definition to the question.

Comment: I added my models in the question.

Comment: Why `Reservation` has no navigation properties `Movie` and `User`?

Comment: I tried putting navigation properties, such as:
public Movie Movie;
public User User;

The syntax in the controller has no errors:

            var reservations = _dbContext.Reservations
                .Include(r => r.Id)
                .Include(c => c.User)
                .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ReservationTime, x.User, x.User.Name });

but when I am trying to run it in the Postman, I receive this error

System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'r.Id' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

Comment: As I mentioned in first comment. `Include` is not applicable to this query. And navigation property should be `Entity` or collection of entities.

Answer (score 0):

If add to `Reservation` navigation properties `Movie` and `User`, your query can be simplified. `Include` cannot be used with `Select` together, it is ignored by EF translator.

```cs
var reservations = _dbContext.Reservations
    .Select(r => new             
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        ReservationTime = r.ReservationTime,
        CustomerName = r.User.Id,
        MovieName = r.Movie.Name
    });
```